# Drupal 6.x CTools

Tags: php, drupal-6, drupal-ctools

We make use of views and panels quite often in Drupal and a lot of people are utilizing CTools in development. I can't find a lot of documentation on what it is and why you'd use it and the drupal.org forum isn't providing much either.

What is CTools, and is it worth using? What is the best use-case for utilizing it?

Comment: Have you looked over the ctools_plugin_examples ? http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions--ctools--ctools_plugin_example--ctools_plugin_example.module/6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Chaos Tool suite is just a set of API's for a better developer's experience. In short, it spices up things and makes it easy to customize some components of Drupal.

Comment: Is there any solid docs / use cases on how to implement it? Thats what I can't find.

Comment: I wonder the same...I can't find out how to use the functions.

Answer (score 0):

You could install module [Advanced help](http://drupal.org/project/advanced_help)